# How to change the CSS in td on mouse click using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

Using JavaScript, I am trying to load CSS (id) on click of a td.

[image: onclick event]

In the above picture, I made main account holder in one td and authorised reporter in another td. Main account holder tab should load while onload. What I required is while clicking the authorised reporters tab the CSS for main account holder and authorised reporter should change. i.e., background for main account holder should apply in authorised reporter place and vice versa.

.css ids are:

```
#account_holder{
         background: url('{{ STATIC_URL }}images/main-account-holder.png')no-repeat;
         background-size:100%;-moz-background-size: cover;
         background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;
         -webkit-background-size: cover;
    }
    #authorised_reportericon{
         background: url('{{ STATIC_URL }}images/authorised_reporter-icon.png')no-repeat;
         background-size:100%;
         -moz-background-size: cover;
         background-size: cover;-webkit-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;
         background-color:#F0F0F0;
         border-top-right-radius: 10px;
         border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    }
    #account_holdericon{
         background: url('{{ STATIC_URL }}images/main-account-holder-icon.png')no-repeat;
         background-size:100%;
         -moz-background-size: cover;
         background-size: cover;
    } 
    #authorised_reporter{
         background: url('{{ STATIC_URL }}images/authorised_reporter.png')no-repeat;background-size:100%;
         -moz-background-size: cover;
         background-size: cover;
         background-color:#F0F0F0;
         border-top-right-radius: 10px;
         border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;   
    }
```

Using JavaScript I want to change the CSS ids while performing onclick. I don't know how to code in JavaScript. Can any one guide me how to code that?

Comment: What you mean by css id, you want to change the id of the element so that respective css applies?

Comment: how to change the id of element on mouse click.

Comment: I would consider not using id and swapping them. instead use classes and change the classes. @Ahmed answer should point you in the right direction.

Comment: ok,how to frame code,if you have a small sample plz post that i will learn and do this

Comment: Simple fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yaA2x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs should be unique. Don't change them. Use classes instead

in Css replace the # to . like the following:

```
.account_holder{
         background: url('{{ STATIC_URL }}images/main-account-holder.png')no-repeat;
         background-size:100%;-moz-background-size: cover;
         background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;
         -webkit-background-size: cover;
    }
```

Here is how to change the class name of an element using javascript:

EDIT:

```
 var your_element = document.getElementById('your_element_id');

   your_element.onclick = function(){
       this.className = 'account_holder';
   };
```

Comment: Since OP doesn't know much about programming in Javascript, please include edit this to include `document.GetElementByID()`

Answer (score 0):

you should use both mouseenter and mouseout event states if using jquery or use hover

Comment: how to do using javascript,any idea if you know plz share